Microsoft Graph APi users/{email}/messages error: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again
Our org. has an email they made in outlook mail. I'm able to use the Microsoft Graph API using the endpoint me/messages but now I wanted to run this in python (in an azure databricks notebook).
So I created a new App in azure portal for this and the only steps I've done otherwise is adding delegated permissions and saving the clientid, secret id, tenant id from there.
I have the below code which throws the error:'Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.' Also, I'm able to get a token..
I've added the following delegated permissions...
email ,Mail.Read ,Mail.ReadWrite, User.Read

And this code:
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
# scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read"]


app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=secret_value
)


result = None
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)

if not result:
    print("No suitable token exists in cache. Requesting a new one...")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)

if "access_token" in result:
    print('using access token...')

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']}
    graph_endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email}/messages'
    response = requests.get(graph_endpoint, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        emails = response.json()
        print(emails)
    else:
        print(f"Error fetching emails: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.json()) 
else:
    print(f"Error acquiring token: {result.get('error')}, {result.get('error_description')}")


Here, you are using client credential flow where there will be no user. So, you need to try /users/userid/messages and apply application permissions rather than delegated permissions for this code to work. If you want a user to login and check his own emails then you need to use Auth code flow to get the token.

believe you need the application permission mail.readbasic.all and mail.read.  I was a bit surprised that you can do this using a client credential flow as that allows you to programatically access any users email. unless I am understanding that incorrectly

The error occurred as you granted permissions of Delegated type which won't work with client credentials flow.
Initially, I too got same error when I ran the code by granting permissions of Delegated type:

To resolve the error, make sure to add Mail.Read permission of Application type by granting admin consent as below:

When I ran the code again after granting permissions of Application type, I got the response successfully like this:
import json
import msal
import requests

tenant_id = "tenantId"
client_id = "appId"
secret_value = "secret"
email = "sri@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=secret_value
)

result = app.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)

if not result:
    print("No suitable token exists in cache. Requesting a new one...")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)

if "access_token" in result:
    print('Using access token...')

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']}
    graph_endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email}/messages'
    response = requests.get(graph_endpoint, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        emails = response.json()
        print(json.dumps(emails, indent=4))
    else:
        print(f"Error fetching emails: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.json()) 
else:
    print(f"Error acquiring token: {result.get('error')}, {result.get('error_description')}")

Response:

